# flutter in android studio says cannot find declaration to go to......i am using the latest version of it v1.7.8+hotfix.4

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

i can't find defination of any of the flutter function or class if i want to see the defination or implementation of `FAB`(floating action button) it says cannot find the  declaration to go to.
here you can see the attached files:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cgv1pNb43SxZtupl_gAYC0gZrd7CQDy_

i have tried deleting the `idea` folder and restarting the android studio

`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

enter code here

```
class ReusableBox extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableBox({@required this.colour, this.cardChild, this.onPress});
  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final Function onPress;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: check flutter config before run Idea  " flutter doctor "

Comment: can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: Open your command line - terminal : then type "flutter doctor"  you will see some output, this output telling you what's the problem .

Comment: [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.239], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[√] VS Code (version 1.36.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

I don't think there is any issue!!

Comment: Nup flutter doctor says "No issues find!!"

Comment: I got this issue and later found out that my code didn't compile, so intelliJ can't even read the section of code that couldn't compile, even for finding declarations.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the Flutter plugin hasn't load the references properly. The Flutter app usually should still be able to run if it doesn't have any errors.

[image: Cannot find declaration]

What you can do here is try running `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` to rebuild the references. If that didn't work, you can restart Android Studio and try running the app.